# Django generate Model Fields from an Array

Tags: python, django

I need to generate a DB Model from an array of strings like this:

```py
strings = ['String 1', 'String 2', ..., 'String N-1', 'String N']
```

I need a table in my DB with this shape

```
ORIGIN | STRING 1 | STRING 2 |...| STRING N
 char  |   char   |   char   |...| char
```

I created my Model Class like this:

```py
class FixedCharField(models.Field):
  def __init__(self, max_length, *args, **kwargs):
    self.max_length = max_length
    super(FixedCharField, self).__init__(max_length=max_length, *args, **kwargs)

  def db_type(self):
    return 'char(%s)' % self.max_length


class MyModel(models.Model):
    strings = get_my_array() # aux function to generate the array
    origin = FixedCharField(max_length=3)
    for string in strings:
        string = FixedCharField(max_length=3)
```

As you can see, I need each column name to have a fixed size of 3, so I used the custom FixedCharField that I found in this link [Fixed Char Field](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9349)

My question is, will this work? And this is the correct approach to do this?

Comment: This will not work sinc it will each time overwrite the `item` variable, hence you end up with only the last one.

Comment: hmm that's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work since here your are each time overwriting the `item` variable, until it gets overwritten for the last time. That will then be the item that Django will "see" after the class is initialized.

You can update the `locals()` dictionary in the class for this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    strings = get_my_array()
    for string in strings:
        locals()[string] = FixedCharField(max_length=3)
```

But still it looks very ugly. It might be better here to contribute your elements to the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # other fields
    pass

for string in get_my_array():
    FixedCharField(max_length=3).contribute_to_class(MyModel, string)
```

Comment: Better yet, though, for code completion, etc., might be to just write a script that generates regular `foo = FixedCharField(...)` statements and paste those in.

Comment: Ohhh that's the correct approach, I see! Thank you. I updated the name of arrays to make more sense, if you want to also update your answer would be helpful to anyone who look for this in the future.